# Date = max(Date) Running Slowly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have about 6 million records in the historical_data table. I am trying to find all symbols where the last recorded row does not equal the highest date on the table. I believe this query will work but it takes forever to run. So long in fact, it times out the connection each time. Is there a way to make this query run faster?

```
select symbol, histDate
from historical_data as a
where histDate =
    (select max(histDate)
     from historical_data as b
     where a.symbol = b.symbol);
```

Comment: Use an uncorrelated subquery instead of a corelated one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an index for this query.  The best index is `historical_data(symbol, histdate)`.

You might find it faster to phrase the query as:

```
select hd.*
from historical_data hd join
     (select symbol, max(histDate) as maxhd
      from historical_data
      group by symbol
     ) s
     on hd.histDate = s.histDate;
```

EDIT:

Oops.  Your sample query doesn't do what the text says you want.  For that:

```
select symbol
from historical_data hd cross join
     (select max(histDate) as maxhd from historical_data) m
group by symbol, maxhd
having max(hd.histDate) <> maxhd;
```

Comment: The last query runs way faster.  Thank you.

Comment: @terryfisher12 . . . The last query also does what you say you want to do.